# Regular expression to check special symbols not working in lightning javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, validation, regular-expressions

I have a validation function in lightning component that works on regex.
I have a regular expression to check existance of special symbols but I am not able to save my js controller with that regular expression.

> Field Integrity Exception:
>   org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException:
>   Unterminated string [663, 65]: ';'<>?,./]/;': Source

```
var regularExpression; 
regularExpression = /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/; //This line is giving error when trying to save 
if(!regularExpression.test(value)) {
     //Action to be taken
}
```

The code works fine with some other regex's

Comment: Looks like the compiler doesn't like this. Did you try to use the `RegExp` constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the constructor syntax.

I've verified that this saves in lightning:

```
var regularExpression; 
var re = new RegExp('[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";\'<>?,.\/]');
```

Note the escape of the `'` char within the expression.

Comment: Hi Caspar Harmer, thanks for the reply. But the same expression isn't working if passed to RegExp constructor in single quotes.

Comment: FYI for others who come here, this has a Salesforce Known Issue that's still "In Review", if you have a minute to go indicate that this affects you, it will help Salesforce see the impact that this has on the broader developer community!

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003Ue8QAE

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the backslash in your expression to make it work.

```
var regularExpression;

var re = new RegExp('[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:";\\'<>?,.\\/]');
```